# Are there any tips for editing the deform mesh cage?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've tried a few times with different methods but I can't seem to get the deform cage right.

Is there a way to cover the mesh with the cage.

[image: Sometimes the mesh is okay like its right leg but then on other parts look messy and crude]

Sculpting seems to get the best result for me

Answer (score 1):

If it's too hard to deal with only one cage, you could deform your mesh with 2 different cages and 2 different *Mesh Deform* modifiers:

- Select your body mesh, enter in *Edit* mode and create 2 different vertex groups, one for each leg.
- Create 2 different cages, each one will encage one of the 2 legs.
- Give your body 2 *Mesh Deform* modifiers. For each modifier choose one of the cage and in the *Vertex Group* field, choose the corresponding vertex group you've created for each leg.
- Click on the *Bind* buttons.
- Now each cage deform only a part of the mesh.

[image]